# Como abrir dialogo para sabes si se quiere cerrar la app (android studio)

Tags: java, android

estoy haciendo una app web, he estado documentandome y no encuentro una forma fácil y efectiva de que se abra un dialogo cuando el usuario esta apunto de cerrar la aplicación y preguntarle si realmente quiere o no cerrarla.

Estoy usando un webview.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Dices que has estado buscando. Qué es lo que has encontrado? Qué has probado? Dónde has tenido fallos o dificultad? Edita tu pregunta y añade el código que has intentado hasta ahora indicando tus problemas. Para editar la pregunta de acuerdo a las normas del sitio puedes leer [tour] y [ask].

Comment: Puedes utilizar el evento onBackPress() y ahi pones tu dialogo de si desea aceptar

Comment: Desde un WebView quieres abrir el diálogo ?, te sugiero agregues lo que has tratado y aporta más información, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea al metodo:

```
  private void cerrarAplicacion() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.alacran)
                    .setTitle("¿Realmente desea cerrar la aplicación?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {// un listener que al pulsar, cierre la aplicacion
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); //Su funcion es algo similar a lo que se llama cuando se presiona el botón "Forzar Detención" o "Administrar aplicaciones", lo cuál mata la aplicación
                            //finish(); Si solo quiere mandar la aplicación a segundo plano
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
```

Mandalo a traer con el evento:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       cerrarAplicacion();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

O bien desde un Boton:

```
tuBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
          cerrarAplicacion();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Genial funciono pero al ser un web view si voy navegando entre ventanas si le doy al boton de atras para volver a la ventana anterior me muestra el mensage no bria un modo de que solo fuera desde la pagina inicial¿?